# Change of Basis of a Line in Hesse Normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, change-of-basis

I have a 2d line expressed in frame {x2, y2}. The line is defined in the Hesse normal form. The perpendicular distance to the line from the origin is $\rho_2$ and the angle from x2 to the perpendicular is $\theta_2$ .

Given $\rho_2$, $\theta_2$ and a defined rotation and translation between frames 1 and 2, I would like to know to transform the Hesse Normal form of the line from frame 2 to frame 1. So, essentially find out the perpendicular distance from the line to the origin of frame 1 $\rho_1$ and the angle from x1 to the perpendicular $\theta_1$.

I have attached an image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w0yY.jpg) with a drawing of the frames and the line.

Thanks in advance.